# Get post count from instagram api

Tags: instagram-api

I am trying to get the post count of an instagram account, I have managed to do followers and following but cant get to get the post count right.

```
<?php
$username = 'instagram';

$response = @file_get_contents( "https://www.instagram.com/$username/?__a=1" );

if ( $response !== false ) {
    $data = json_decode( $response, true );
    if ( $data !== null ) {
        $full_name = $data['graphql']['user']['full_name'];
        $follower  = $data['graphql']['user']['edge_followed_by']['count'];
        $follows = $data['graphql']['user']['edge_follow']['count'];
        echo "<p>{$full_name}</p> <p>{$follower} followers {$follows} following.</p>";
    }
} else {
echo 'Username not found.';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

If anyone ever needs the answer, I managed to pull it through...

```
<?php
$username = 'instagram';

$response = @file_get_contents( "https://www.instagram.com/$username/?__a=1" );

if ( $response !== false ) {
   $data = json_decode( $response, true );
   if ( $data !== null ) {
      $full_name = $data['graphql']['user']['full_name'];
      $follower  = $data['graphql']['user']['edge_followed_by']['count'];
      $follows = $data['graphql']['user']['edge_follow']['count'];
      $posts = $data['graphql']['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['count'];
      echo "<h2><a href='https://www.instagram.com/{$username}'>{$full_name}</a></h2> 
      <p><span>{$posts} posts</span> <span>{$follower} followers</span>  <span>{$follows} following</span></p>";
     }
} else {
echo 'Username not found.';
}
?>
```

You can get many options by just going to 
https://www.instagram.com/$username/?__a=1
and changing the $username to the account you need to see