# Get post count from instagram api 2021

Tags: php, json, instagram, instagram-api

I was using this code until yesterday and it ran without any problems
But it does not work any more

[Get post count from instagram api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57144315/get-post-count-from-instagram-api)

```
    <?php
$username = 'instagram';

$response = @file_get_contents( "https://www.instagram.com/$username/?__a=1" );

if ( $response !== false ) {
   $data = json_decode( $response, true );
   if ( $data !== null ) {
      $full_name = $data['graphql']['user']['full_name'];
      $follower  = $data['graphql']['user']['edge_followed_by']['count'];
      $follows = $data['graphql']['user']['edge_follow']['count'];
      $posts = $data['graphql']['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['count'];
      echo "<h2><a href='https://www.instagram.com/{$username}'>{$full_name}</a></h2> 
      <p><span>{$posts} posts</span> <span>{$follower} followers</span>  <span>{$follows} following</span></p>";
     }
} else {
echo 'Username not found.';
}
?>
```

Comment: That `/$username/?__a=1` stuff has been semi-retired, resp. is not an official API endpoint any more. You will have to look into the new IG APIs, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram - both the IG Graph API and the Basic Display API have a `media_count` property on the user object. But this will also require login/authentication.